# I want to show my all comments by clicking an anchor but I don't know how

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

A function like this is showing comments on my website

```
$retrieve = $con->select2("*", "`comments`", "page_id=" . $page_id, "`comments`.`id` DESC LIMIT ".$con->comnt_limit);
```

where

```
$comnt_limit = 5;
```

I want that when I click on an anchor like this

```
<a href="" id="show_all">Show all Comments</a>
```

my **$comnt_limit = $show_all** where i have **$show_all** variable which contains total number of rows in my mysql table and now the above function that retrieve my data run and show all comments on the same page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#show_all').click(function (event) {
    $.ajax('url', options);
});
```

cf. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for the options.

And instead of settings the limit to a high number you should remove it completely.